# Performant Redshift query to return year and shipping mode with max count?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table **lineitem** with 303 million rows. The sortkey is on **l_receiptdate**.

| l_receiptdate | l_shipmode |
| --- | --- |
| 1992-01-03 | TRUCK |
| 1992-01-03 | TRUCK |
| 1992-03-03 | SHIP |
| 1993-02-03 | AIR |
| 1993-05-03 | SHIP |
| 1993-07-03 | AIR |
| 1993-09-05 | AIR |

Ultimate goal: find what shipmode was used the most for each year.  Return year, shipmode, and count for that most popular ship mode.

**Expected output**:

| receiptyear | shipmode | ship_mode_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1992 | TRUCK | 2 |
| 1993 | AIR | 3 |

I'm new to Redshift and it's nuances.  I know 303 million rows isn't considered big data but I'd like to start learning Redshift best query practices from the beginning.  Below is what I have so far, not sure how to move forward:

```sql
select DATE_TRUNC('year', l_receiptdate) as receiptyear,
       l_shipmode as shipmode,
       count(*) as ship_mode_count
FROM lineitem
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine, in a general sense.  The missing piece of data is what is the distribution key of the table? You see Redshift is a clustered (distributed) database and this distribution is controlled by the DISTSTYLE and DISTKEY of the table.

Here's a simple way to think about the performance of a Redshift query.  Given the nature of Redshift there are few aspects that tend to dominate poorly performing queries:

1. Too much network redistribution of data
2. Scanning too much data from disk
3. Spilling to disk, making more data than needed through cross or looped joins, and a whole bunch of other baddies.

Your query has no joins so #3 isn't an issue.  Your query needs to scan the entire table from disk so there is nothing that can be better in #2.  However, #1 is where your could get in trouble especially when your data grows.

Your query needs to group by the ship mode and the year.  This means that all the data for each unique combination of these needs to be brought together.  So if your table was distributed by ship mode (don't do this)
then all the data for each value would reside on a single "slice" of the database and no network data transmission would be needed to perform the count.  However you don't to do this in this case since you are just dealing with a COUNT() function and Redshift is smart enough to count locally and then ship the partial results, which are much smaller than the original data, to one place for the final count.

If more complicated actions were being performed that can't be done in parts, then the distribution of the table could make a big difference to the query.  Having the data all in one place when rows need to be combined (join, group by, partition, etc) can prevent a lot of data needed to be shipped around the cluster via the network.

Your query will work fine but hopefully walking through this mental exercise helps you understand Redshift better.